# java.io.IOException: Initialization of all the collectors failed. Error in last collector was :null

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a newbie in MapReduce and I am trying to find a solution to a problem.I am trying to chain two map reduce jobs.The first job is getting executed but on the second job I am getting an error as follows

```
     INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1445271708293_0055_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Initialization of all the collectors failed.              Error in last collector was :null
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:1011)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:402)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please review my answer to your issue here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54454365/1566372

Answer (score 3):

I had imported Text in Driver class as

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider.Text
```

instead of

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
```

because of which I was getting the error, once I rectified the mistake it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same error when output types from map task didn't matched with input types of reduce task.

Last two arguments in mapper should have the same type as first two in reducer.

```
public class ByteCalculationMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

public class ByteCalculationReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
```